# Filter KendoUI Grid Server and Client Side

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I need to filter a few columns in the Kendo UI grid server side and few client side only. I know that the Kendo UI Grid does not support mixed filter options. I am still wondering if there is any other way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I fear there isn't any such feature in kendo UI to my knowledge. Instead you could use kendoGrid filter for client side filters and can have a separate custom filters containing values of column filters that are to be done in the server side in a combobox. On user selecting the combobox you can send request to server filtering, while the kendo grid local filters works for other columns.

Comment: do you have an example for me?